# What does it mean when F values of ANOVAs are not all ~0?

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric

I am running an aligned rank transform ANOVA (a non-parametric ANOVA for an ordinal DV). In my data there are 3 factors and one ordinal DV.

When I create the model:
`m = art(Distressed ~ x1 * x2 * x3 + (1|pid), data=df)`, I get the warning:

```
F values of ANOVAs on aligned responses not of interest are not all ~0. ART may not be appropriate.

F values of ANOVAs on aligned responses not of interest (should all be ~0):
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0944  0.0264  1.3615      12
```

I also get the warning: `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 7 columns / coefficients` 7 times. This would imply that it is dropping 14 columns, but I only have 12 columns total in my dataframe and when inspecting the model it appears all columns are still present. From googling, I have discovered that this error is because not all of my dimensions are linearly independent. But this is strange because I have ordinal and nominal data so I am unsure how they can be "correlated".

So my question here is:

1. What does it mean if F values of ANOVAS on aligned responses are not ~0? Looking at the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ARTool/readme/README.html) this means that effects not of interest weren't successfully "stripped out". Why would this fail? Is this something that needs to be fixed? And if so, how would I go about fixing it?
2. I am assuming the fact that the columns seem to be linearly dependent may stem from R doing erroneous type inference. This is because since the columns are nominal and ordinal and thus cannot be correlated, so in order to find a correlation R would need to be treating 7(?) of these columns as ratio or interval values. Based off this I assume it is okay to ignore this warning...